# MacBook Pro Intermittent internet connection

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, internet

Some of you may know about some weird issue with some MacBook Pros (MBP) not working properly with a router (SuperHub) supplied by Virgin (a UK ISP).

In all my attempts to resolve this, I finally got a little mini-like router/AP. Turned the SuperHub into a modem and used this mini-like device as a router. Then I was able to narrow down something I can't get my head past.

***The puzzle***:

2 computers (an iMac and a MacBook Pro) connected to the same network - wirelessly. Only the 2 systems on the network.

How is it that one of them constantly looses connection to the internet and the other doesn't?

***How did I figure this out?***

I opened 2 terminal window on both machines. One window constantly pings the router and another window pings google.

On the MBP, the connection to the router hardly drops. but the connection to google drops constantly. Stays down for almost a minute sometimes - if not more.

On the other hand, none of the connection on the iMac drops at all - hardly.

How is this possible? What could be the cause?

Comment: Are you connecting to 2.4 or 5Ghz network (are both of the machines connect to the same network)?
Does moving MBP next to the AP changes anything (if yes, then you have wireless signal strength/obstruction problem or something is wrong with your wifi adapter)?
Can you try the same setup with a different AP/router?

Comment: Yes! Both machines were once on the same network - 5GHz. But what I did was to eliminate the chance it was due to the wireless from the superhub. So got a private router/access point and connected to the router through it. Still same intermittent connections. Which is where my post/question came from. Also, moving the MBP closer does not solve it. And no other router in the house. Tempted to buy another, just want to be sure before I spend some money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's official. A post in the above post was the answer.

Not sure exactly what step solved it, but ***I deleted the .plist file as stated. Then did the PRAM and SMC reset.***

And my goodness, for 4 hours straight - its been nothing but flawless.

Hopefully won't encounter the problem again. But if I do, will try to find out what the actual solution is amongst the above steps I took.

Thanks again!.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar question to this which I answered.  I believe the OP ended getting a "version 2 Superhub" from Virgin which solved his particular issues.

Check this out:

[Wifi Keeps Dropping Macbook Pro 13in Retina Early 2015](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195359/wifi-keeps-dropping-macbook-pro-13in-retina-early-2015)

You also want to check how crowded your Wi-Fi is.  When you view all the wi-fi networks in your area, how many show up?  The more networks, the more traffic, and the more issues you are going to run into.

Comment: So, just had a look. Thanks for this. Must say, I have tried it all except one suggestion from that link. The possible solution regarding the Plist, resetting the SMC etc. Regarding the superhub, I have the latest version - superhub 2. Issues of overcrowding is not an issue either, for I once used sky router and all was well.

Comment: Think it is official and it has something to do with Virgin routers (superHub2). Just left a mates house, where they have the same router and guess what, that same issue. I am now in Costa ad have not experienced not a drop in internet connection. Under our old ISP with their own router, no issues too. Only this SuperHub 2. I would have opted to use a different cable modem all together. But the fella from Virgin said that won't be possible, as virgin only allows approved mac address on their network - i.e. only Virgin's routers. Why this is, I don't know.

Comment: That's bollocks.  They do it so they can squeeze every last bit of revenue they can from you.  Across the pond they allow you to use any modem that is DOCSIS 3.0 compatible.  I wish you the best in getting this resolved with Virgin.