# Wi-Fi issue with MacOS X El Capitan

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, macos

I have a MacBook Pro with retina display model A1502. I updated it to MacOS X El Capitan.
The Wi-Fi connection is still not working.
It works for sleep mode.

I followed this answer [Wifi Keeps Dropping Macbook Pro 13in Retina Early 2015](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195359/wifi-keeps-dropping-macbook-pro-13in-retina-early-2015) but it is not working for me.

Comment: To get correct answers rather than advice to read receipes to fix other problems, please describe your wireless environment (within your original question rather than comment). What is your wireless router? How far is it? On which channel is it running? How many wireless network from neighboors do you see from your MacBook Pro?

Comment: If you can find another way to connect your MacBook Pro to the Internet, download the last free version of iStumbler: https://istumbler.net/archive/release99/ , run it on your MacBook Pro configured on a Wi-Fi network configuration (even if it is failing). Make a screen capture of iStumbler, and insert it within your original question to get qualified answers.

Comment: Within the question you followed and quoted, did you apply this one which is the best: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/195367/22003 ?

Comment: What did you try from the other posts? You should post a bounty on the existing question instead if none of them worked for you and you've the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Exact the same issue.
Only my MBP with El Capitan could not connect to wifi (always turn off and turn on to work for seconds), but just at home, not at office.
I fixed with a **firmware update** of the router and access point (fritz!box), I also **changed wifi radio channel** and **set wifi standard to n+g+b**.

Comment: This is suppurting my reply: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/199825/152038