# Can connect to router but not internet

Tags: macos, wifi, internet

My MacBook (El Capitan 10.11.2) one day cannot connect to the internet via wifi. It work solidly beforehand.

My router setting has not changed. Nor have any device white/black-listing.
Other devices can connect to the router and internet fine.

- `ping 192.168.1.1` works
- `nslookup stackexchange.com` works
- `nslookup stackexchange.com 8.8.8.8` fails
- `ping stackexchange.com` times out

Interestingly if I connect to the Router's wifi guest, it works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi Keeps Dropping Macbook Pro 13in Retina Early 2015](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195359/wifi-keeps-dropping-macbook-pro-13in-retina-early-2015)

Answer (score 1):

So a desktop that's connecting to the router via ethernet cable experience the same exact problem! Many other devices operated fine. This allow me to pinpoint the router is messed up somehow.

A power down restart on the router fixed everything.

Comment: Nice! When in doubt...turn it off and back on again.