# Intermittent AirPort issue on MacBook Pro Early 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, airport, dns

I have an Apple MacBook Pro Early 2015, with AirPort issues.

The problem is extremely complex, but effectively it means I get page time out intermittently.

- I've reinstalled macOS from scratch, without backup, twice.
- The issue only happens on Wi-Fi.
- It happens when on WPA Personal Wi-Fi, but not Enterprise, unsure about Unsecured and WEP.
- It happens on 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz on any wireless channel, regardless of interference.
- I can still ping local devices, but HTTP requests to the router's config page for example do not work, and internet requests either.
- It isn't DNS related as I've tried 3 DNSs and tested with IP addresses
- There is no Firewall, or tools like LittleSnitch running
- I can see when the issue occours by pinging 8.8.8.8
- Other devices on the same internet connection both wired and wireless are unaffected.
- The issue is resolved by a reboot.
- I've reproduced this at other locations, as well as trying a new Router from my ISP, Virgin Media, and buying a Ubiquiti UniFi AP-AC-LR
- We've run Wireless Diagnostics, which Apple Engineering has looked at and not found anything.
- They have changed the AirPort card
- Tried PRAM and SMC resets, and most the stuff on this thread:
  [Wifi Keeps Dropping Macbook Pro 13in Retina Early 2015](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195359/wifi-keeps-dropping-macbook-pro-13in-retina-early-2015)

I'm completely out of ideas, Apple are refusing to replace the Mac, and my work colleague has the identical issue on a newer but same model of MacBook Pro.

Does anyone have any idea how to proceed, I have been waiting for Apple to deal with this and they seem to have no idea, what the issue is.

Comment: Try to look at the traffic with [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Updating to the latest major OS earlier this month was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by upgrading to macOS Sierra.