# Frequent Wired Internet Disconnects on MacBook Pro 2018 (ethernet)

Tags: macbook-pro

MacBook Pro only, other stuff on network is normal, nearby windows PC is normal. --Internet connection drops random about 6-10 times per hour - - Ethernet Green - - Network Settings Green --The IP address is set manually

Comment: give a try by putting 8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4 on DNS and check it how it goes ? It will help to know more.

Comment: Before you go changing DNS settings as @Udhy suggested, let's start by diagnosing your connection.  Can you ping the router?  Also, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/195367/119271).  Even though it references WiFi, the concepts are the same.