# Wifi dropping out for no particular reason

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

My wifi connection keeps dropping and I have no idea why. The only network related thing I have installed is ExpressVPN, but I have had it installed for a while and there has been no problems. I rarely use the VPN.

I have reset PRAM and it is still happening. Not sure what else to do. Any help would be nice.

My computer is....

MacBook Pro (16-inch 2019), 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9, 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB. MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3

[Here is my log file...](https://pastebin.com/VLpEd1Te)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wifi Keeps Dropping Macbook Pro 13in Retina Early 2015](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195359/wifi-keeps-dropping-macbook-pro-13in-retina-early-2015)

Comment: I will try those troubleshooting steps - thank you!!